# Cannot View Local Storage in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to view what is in my local storage in Google Chrome, but when I click on *Inspect > Application*, but unlike what others are seeing, I see no menu on the left:

[image]

Do I need to enable something?

Comment: You didn't click on `Application` judging by the screenshot.

Comment: Nothing happens when I click on it.

Comment: It should work so your browser is bugged. Try updating Chrome as suggested in the top upper corner.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + Shift + I Application --> Local Storage

Comment: Thank You!! I've been trying to figure this out for a couple days now.